# Is this limit zero as $(h,k)$ goes to $(0,0)$? $({h^2}\sin(1/h) + {k^2}\sin(1/k) )/ \sqrt{h^{2} + k^{2} } $

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$F(h,k)$ is given by $({h^2}\sin(1/h) + {k^2}\sin(1/k)) / \sqrt{h^{2} + k^{2}}$. If it is zero doesn't sin terms screw whole thing up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$$
\left|\frac{h^2\sin\frac1h+k^2\sin\frac1k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\right|=
\left|h\sin\frac1h\frac{h}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}   
+k\sin\frac1k\frac{k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}  \right|
\leq\left|  h\sin\frac1h\right|+\left|k\sin\frac1k\right|,
$$
but the last tend to 0.

Comment: thanks a lot for beautiful answer

Comment: question not edited peoperly

Comment: @SophieClad I have added LaTeX formatting. You can correct your question now according to your wishes.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different approach:

$$\left|\frac{h^2\sin\frac1h+k^2\sin\frac1k}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}\right|\le\frac{h^2+k^2}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=\sqrt{h^2+k^2}\xrightarrow[(h,k)\to(0,0)]{}0$$